# Sent tcp data to ip

Tags: php, tcp

My plan is to make a local website (wamp?).

On that website you can enter a link to get the time from (example: time.windows.com). 
When you click on sent it will sent data (string of the website) to the ip.

Then I recieve the string of the website wich I can use as variable.

Is that possible in php? If so how?

I have made an drawing to explain it better:

[image]

Comment: What is the point of doing this? The time on **YOUR** web site will be delayed (by your web server and the network between your machine and the time server). Besides the user could go straight to the horses mouth

Comment: I will not sent the time in the tcp connection but just the name of the server to use in the Cortex M3. So I can easly change the time on my board without compiling

Comment: You question was not very clear. Perhaps an edit would not go amiss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible. You can use [`fsockopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) to open socket connections.